# Ubuntu 14.04: install nutch 1.9 and Solr to

Tags: ubuntu, solr, nutch

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit) on a Oracle Virtualbox.
I am looking for the compatible version of Solr and Nutch for this VM.
And instructions on installing both Solr and Nutch.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use every Nutch version with any solr version. Nutch connect solr with solrj. At the default Nutch 1.9 use solrj 3.4. Nutch 2.x use solrj 4.6.0 If you use solr 3.4 and higher version, It is compatible. IMHO if you use different version Solr you should change solrj version and build it.